# Cannot get last location although permissions are granted

Tags: java, android, android-activity, location, location-services

I have the following class, that is extended by all my activities, where I want to save the last location using LocationServices.

Debugging it seems that permissions are granted, and I enter the onComplete method, but task.getResult() is always null. How is this possible?

```
public class MyAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else
        setUserLocation();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setUserLocation();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void setUserLocation() {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
            ROUserInfo user = UserManager.getROUserInfo();
            if(user==null || task.getResult()==null)
                return;
            user.User._Position._Latitude=task.getResult().getLatitude();
            user.User._Position._Longitude=task.getResult().getLongitude();
            UserManager.updateUserOnServer(user);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Could please check for GPS enabled or not in your device ?
Or you can open once google map inside your device. and then check with your application.

Comment: You are right. I was trying the app on the emulator, and for some reason it doesn't see the location, although I've set it in the emulator settings.
Trying the app on a physical device solved the problem.
Thanks.